# Conditions for Thevenin and Norton non-existance

Tags: basic, thevenin, norton

It's not clear to me when a Thevenin or Norton equivalent *cannot* be produced for a given linear circuit. Can anyone help me with a clear definition?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your question is not clear.  A circuit containing only resistors obeying Ohm' law will always have a Thevenin equivalent.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right. I meant a circuit made with resistors _and_ voltage or current sources.

Comment: I've changed the original question to reflect my error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a resistive electrical network \$\mathcal{N}\$ to be representable with a Thévenin or Norton's equivalent circuits, the following conditions should apply [1]:

1. The network \$\mathcal{N}\$ should be *well defined*, that is, it should not be coupled to an external physical variable. This condition is usually tacitly assumed in circuit theory books.
2. The network \$\mathcal{N}\$ should be *linear* and *time invariant*. This conditions are probably already familiar to you, because the Thévenin and Norton's equivalent circuits are typically presented in basic circuit theory books which mainly deal with linear time-invariant networks.
3. The network \$\mathcal{N}\$ should be *uniquely solvable*. This condition has the purpose of eliminating pathological networks, and it is frequently missed in basic circuit theory books. The *uniquely solvability* conditions takes two forms, whether you consider the Thévenin's representation or the Norton's one. For the Thévenin's representation it is required that the complete network obtained by connecting a current source to \$\mathcal{N}\$ has a unique solution for each value of the injected current. For the Norton's representation it is required that the complete network obtained by connecting a voltage source to \$\mathcal{N}\$ has a unique solution for each value of the applied voltage.

For instance, an ideal voltage source does not have a Norton's equivalent, and an ideal current source does not have a Thévenin's equivalent. They both violate the respective uniquely solvability conditions.

There are extremely pathological circuits that possess neither a Thévenin's equivalent nor a Norton's one. An example is the following (the diamond represents a current controlled current source):

[image]

The above circuit possess neither a Thévenin's equivalent nor a Norton's one between terminals A and B, because it has only one operating point, namely \$i=0\$ and \$v_\mathrm{AB}=0\$, whatever you apply between terminals A and B.

You can find a proof of the Thévenin and Norton's theorems, with details on the above conditions, in the cited book [1].

[1] L. Chua, C. A. Desoer, and E. S. Kuh, *Linear and nonlinear circuits*, McGraw-Hill, 1987.

Comment: Thanks Massimo! You're right. I don't seem to find these conditions listed in a number of books i've been using.

Comment: The picture clarifies the corner case further, thanks.